# How to play a List of videos and audios on mobile devices (HTML5 )

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, video-streaming, html5-video, playlist

I am trying to solve a problem of playing a list of selected videos and audio clips on mobile devices in a browser without user intervention.

I generate a list of URLs of videos and audios. ( I store it in an array).

Then I want to play the list (of URLs of Videos and Audio) continuously, non-stop without user intervention, for example, without involving user to click every clip to play.

I have tried it in HTML 5 with mobile jquery. It is indeed working well on desktop HTML5 enabled browser but it is not working on mobile devices the way I want due to the fact the autoplay feature is disabled on mobile browsers. Existing code given below.

I am willing to using any other solution, as long as it plays list of URLs of Videos and 
Audios on mobile  devices in a mobile browser continuously.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I really need to solve this problem.
Thanks.
TJ

```
function NextFrag(){

if (index < URLArray.length)
{
   if(index == 0 )
   {
        $("#VideoContainer").html('<video  id="video1" controls ="controls" > "<source src= "'+ URLArray[index]+ '" type="video/mp4"></source> </video>' );                     
        index++;
        $("#video1").bind( "ended", NextFrag);
    }
    else
    {
     $("#VideoContainer").html('<video  id="video1" controls autoplay > "<source src= "'+ URLArray[index]+ '" type="video/mp4"></source> </video>' );
     index++;
     $("#video1").bind( "ended", NextFrag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continuously play a list of videos/audios using `<video>` or `<audio>` element on mobile devices you have to:

1. create only one such element,
2. start playing it with user interaction (because it's impossible to execute the play() method of media element on mobile devices without user action, such as a click/touch event),
3. and then change only "src" attribute of it

If you remove that media element from DOM then you'll loose the 'scope' of user action event and the next video will need another user action (click/touch) to start it.

The simplest implementation of such continuous looping playlist using jQuery:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<button id="playBtn">Play</button>

<script>

var videos = [
    'video1.mp4',
    'video2.mp4',
    'video3.mp4'
    ],
    mediaElement,        
    container,
    playBtn,
    currentItem = 0;

function createVideo(){

    mediaElement = $('<video/>').attr({
        id: 'vid', 
        preload: "none"
    }).prop({
        controls: true
    }).css({
        width: '480px',
        height: '360px',
        position: 'relative'
    });

    // listen to the events
    mediaElement.on('loadstart', playVideo);
    mediaElement.on('ended', endedListener);

    // add <video> element to the DOM
    container.append(mediaElement);
}

function applySrc(src){
    mediaElement.attr('src', src); // just change the 'src' attribute
    mediaElement[0].load(); // important on iOS
}

function changeVideo(itemId){
    applySrc(videos[itemId]);
}

function removeVideo(){
    if(mediaElement){
        mediaElement.remove();
    }
}

function playVideo(){
    mediaElement[0].play();
}

function endedListener(evt){
    currentItem >= videos.length - 1 ? currentItem = 0 : currentItem++;
    changeVideo(currentItem);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    playBtn = $('#playBtn');
    container = $('#player');
    playBtn.on('click', function(){
       removeVideo();
       createVideo();
       applySrc(videos[currentItem]);
    });
});
</script>
```

Please remember not to use global scope to define that functions - here it's just to simplify the example.

I've successfully tested that solution on:

- iPhone 5 iOS 7.0.4 Safari
- iPad 2 iOS 7.0.4 Safari
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 - GT-P3100 - Android 4.0.3 - native, Chrome, Firefox
- Samsung Galaxy SIII - GT-I9300 - Android 4.2.2 - native browser, Chrome, Firefox
- Nokia Lumia 925 - Windows Phone 8.0 - IEMobile 10

It's working fine on all desktop browsers too.

Comment: @fixedmachine.. Thank you for your input I have made note of it and will be using in future. I really needed something without user intervention but thats not possible.